# python, mpi and shell subprocess: orte_error_log

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, mpi

I have written a small code in `python 2.7` for launching 4 independent processes on the shell via `subprocess`, using the library `mpi4py`. I am getting ORTE_ERROR_LOG and I would like to understand where it is happening and why.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import re
import sys
from mpi4py import MPI

def main():
    root='base'
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    if comm.rank == 0:
        job = [root+str(i) for i in range(4)]
    else:
        job = None

    job = comm.scatter(job, root=0)
    cmd="../../montepython/montepython/MontePython.py -conf ../config/default.conf -p ../config/XXXX.param -o ../chains/XXXX  -N 10000 > XXXX.log"

    cmd_job = re.sub(r"XXXX", job, cmd)
    subprocess.check_call(cmd_job, shell=True)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I am running with the command:

```
mpirun -np 4 ./run.py
```

This is the error message that I get:

```
[localhost:51087] [[51455,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file base/odls_base_default_fns.c at line 1762
[localhost:51087] [[51455,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file orted/orted_comm.c at line 916
[localhost:51087] [[51455,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file base/odls_base_default_fns.c at line 1762
[localhost:51087] [[51455,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file orted/orted_comm.c at line 916
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
A system call failed during shared memory initialization that should
not have.  It is likely that your MPI job will now either abort or
experience performance degradation.

  Local host:  localhost
  System call: open(2) 
  Error:       No such file or directory (errno 2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I cannot understand where the error is happening. `MontePython` by itself should not use `mpi` because it should be serial.

---

I asked for help to the openmpi user forum. They told me that the problem is likely due to a bad interaction between the subprocess and MPI implementation. I should change from `subprocess` to `spawn`, but this function is not very well documented, I am unsure how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

```
[localhost:51087] [[51455,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file base/odls_base_default_fns.c at line 1762
[localhost:51087] [[51455,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file orted/orted_comm.c at line 916
[localhost:51087] [[51455,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file base/odls_base_default_fns.c at line 1762
[localhost:51087] [[51455,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file orted/orted_comm.c at line 916
```

Those are occurring in the part of the ORTE framework that is responsible for launching and controlling the MPI processes. It could be because there is not enough space in the temporary directory where Open MPI is storing the session information.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
A system call failed during shared memory initialization that should
not have.  It is likely that your MPI job will now either abort or
experience performance degradation.

  Local host:  localhost
  System call: open(2) 
  Error:       No such file or directory (errno 2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This error is coming from the module that implements shared-memory intranode communication in Open MPI. The cause is most likely that `tmpfs` is mounted in some non-standard place or is not mounted at all. Without the shared-memory module, the library will either use the slower TCP/IP module (if enabled, which it is by default) or crash the application as no other means to communicate between will remain.

Both error messages have probably nothing to do with your program. Try something simpler, e.g. the canonical "Hello World!" example in order to confirm that Open MPI is functioning correctly.